# Dynamic UIView in UITabBaritem

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbaritem

Basically what I have is View with a series of `UIButtons` and depending on what button is pressed a View with `UITabBar` is displayed with a certain `UITabBarItem` selected. 
  This works out fine, however what I want to do is to change the `UIView` within the `UITabBarItem`. 
So for example: I have 8 buttons on the my first view. I press button 1 and `UITabBarItem` 2 is selected and **View A** is displayed, however if I press button 2 `UITabBarItem` 2 is selected but instead of View **A** it displays View **B**. 
What exactly is happening is, if I have `viewDidLoad` method the code within is preloaded before I can change it dynamically. So I tried using `viewWillAppear` but nothing seems to happen. 
Any help will be appreciated. I hope I have made my question clear enough for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement the uitabbarcontroller protocol and overwrite
these methods:

```
– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however I have realized this are more complex than that.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that on top of the UITabBarController I actually have a series of UIButtons which act as a custom UITabBar. so once a button is press it is not detected by any of the methods. Is there a way around this?

Comment: in my opinion you have to link that button to a custom selector on the tap event and then call manually the protocol methods